# Filter fields with space character from csv file on command line

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, csv

A csv file with multiple records is delimited by `|`.

```
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
```

I want to check if field3 is blank or contains "space" characters only. 
If it is blank or space, the whole line should show up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ echo "1|2||4" | awk  -F'|' '$3 ~ /^[ \t]*$/   {print $0}'

1|2||4

$ echo "1|2|  |4" | awk  -F'|' '$3 ~ /^[ \t]*$/   {print $0}'

1|2|  |4

$ echo "1|2|  3|4" | awk  -F'|' '$3 ~ /^[ \t]*$/   {print $0}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the cut command to pull out the third field and then test the value:

```
$ echo "field1|field2|field3|field4|field5" | cut -d '|' -f 3
field3
```

Comment: More readable than awk for this trivial situation if y' ask me (which nobody did ;))

Answer (score 1):

My random attempt using `grep` would be:

```
grep -E '^[^|]*\|[^|]*\| *[^| ]+ *\|' file
```

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that it isn't general, so if you want to select on the 14th field it would become hateful.

Comment: @James: Then try something like: "grep -E '^([^|]*\|){13} *[^| ]+ *\|' file" adjusting the value "13" appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about unix, but in linux you would want to use the sed command.

sed 's/||/\n/g' will make it so that if there are any blank fields it will add a new line. not certain how to get it to only check the 3rd field.
sed 's/| |/\n/g' should work for only spaces.

Comment: linux is a form of unix. Most things that are in linux are in other unixes.

Comment: was this comment necessary? Sed, Awk, Grep and the like are SIMILAR across *NIX and BSD systems, but not always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

`perl -F'\|' -lane 'print if $F[2] !~ /\S/' file`

`-a` turns on autosplit mode, which splits the fields into array `@F`
`-F'\|'` sets the field delimiter to `|`
`$F[2]` is the 3rd field
`!~ /\S/` tests for non-space characters (or empty)